# How to recognize the application finished execution when initiated remotely through JSCH?

Tags: java, jsch, channel

Here is the scenario..

I am running an application remotely via ssh(JSCH)..  Now , I want to read data from a file(which is constantly updating some values) when the application starts till the application ends. 
I starts copying the data from that file to another destination file before going for "channel.connect" which starts the application...

Now, my problem is how to know when the application is done, so that I can stop copying the data from file to file?

I have tried options like channel.isClosed and isEOF to check whether the application have ended! but seems both doesn't work and the code is running continuously(due to the while loop)

[ I have read that channel doesn't need to get closed by itself even though the command is executed..]... so what can I do???   Can Anybody please suggest me some way to get this done!!?

```
       String fileNameToRead = "fileNameToRead";
      File file =new File(fileNameToRead );                 
      File statText =
              new File(destinationFile);

     FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);
     OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
     Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);        

     String lastLine="--check--";

      InputStream in=channelForApplication.getInputStream();

      channelForApplication.connect();          

    byte[] tmp=new byte[1024]; 
    while(true){

        lastLine=getLastLine(file);  // method to get the last line of the Constantly updating file.
        w.write(lastLine);
        w.write("\n");           

        while(in.available()>0){                
          int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);  
          System.out.println(new String(tmp, 0, i));
          if(i<0)break;          
        }   
       // System.out.printf("Get the EOF FUNCTION To CHECK-->"+channelForApplication.isEOF());
        if(channelForApplication.isEOF()){
              System.out.println("exit-status: "+channelForApplication.getExitStatus()+"   >  "); 
              if (channelForApplication.getExitStatus() < 0) {
                System.out.println("Done, but exit status not set!");

            } else if (channelForApplication.getExitStatus() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Done, but with error!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Done!");
            }
              channelForAverageCPU.disconnect();                
              System.out.println("the channel for av disconnected from init appl");
              channelForApplication.disconnect();
              w.close();
               break;

            }
       }
```

Comment: Where is your code for opening the channel?

Comment: Channel channelForApplication=channelForApplication=session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channelForApplication).setCommand(commandForApplication);          
        
        channelForApplication.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channelForApplication).setErrStream(System.err);